# Why does overloading __setitem__ using setattrib not work as expected?

Tags: python, inheritance

I am building a simple observable list that triggers observer functions when the list is changed. To avoid repeating virtually the same code over and over again for each method I decorate the methods that make changes to the list with a `for` loop and `setattr`. The methods I want to decorate are stored in `methods_to_decorate`. Here's my class definition.

```py
class ObservableList(list):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.observers = []
        self._decorate_methods()

    def register_observer(self, callback):
        self.observers.append(callback)

    def _trigger_observers(self):
        for func in self.observers:
            func()

    def _make_observable(self, func):
        """Decorator that makes a method observable"""
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            self._trigger_observers()
            return value
        return wrapper

    def _decorate_methods(self):
        """Make methods that change the list observable 
        using the decorator
        """
        methods_to_decorate = [
            '__setitem__', '__reversed__', '__delitem__', 
            'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'extend', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 
            'reverse', 'sort'
        ]
        for attr in methods_to_decorate:
            setattr(self, attr, self._make_observable(getattr(self, attr)))
```

Note that `__setitem__` is one of the decorated methods. This behaves as expected, except for slice setting operations:

```py
def my_observer():
    print(' -> The list was changed')

lst = ObservableList([1, 2, 3])
lst.register_observer(my_observer)
print('append() should trigger')
lst.append(4)                   # -> The list was changed
print('pop() should trigger')
lst.pop()                       # -> The list was changed
print('Slice reading should not trigger')
lst[0]                          # (no output, expected)
print('Slice writing should trigger')
lst[0] = 0                      # (no output, not expected)
```

Setting a slice does not trigger the observer. However, if I overwrite `__setitem__` (which handles slice setting) explicitly, the object behaves as expected and slice setting also triggers the observer:

```py
    # Only if __setitem__ is overloaded explicitly 
    # the observers are triggered on slice setting. 
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        self._trigger_observers()
```

Why does overloading `__setitem__` explicitly work but why does overloading it with its decorated version using `setattr` not work?

Comment: Setting magic methods on an instance doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I completely understand what you mean by that. Could you elaborate a bit more on that? And if it doesn't work, why doesn't it throw an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of user2357112 supports Monica pointed me into the direction where I found the answer. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21990465/12646289), `setattr` overwrites the methods of the *object instance*, while the explicit overloading changes the definition of the class itself. By design magic methods (i.e. methods starting with double underscores) cannot be overridden on instance level. So `__setitem__` and the other magic methods have to be overloaded explicitly in the class definition.